# ExecuteProcess vs. ExecuteStreamCommand in NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

NiFi documentation defines `ExecuteProcess` and `ExecuteStreamCommand` as follows:

### ExecuteProcess

> Runs an operating system command specified by the user and writes the output of that command to a FlowFile. If the command is expected to be long-running, the Processor can output the partial data on a specified interval. When this option is used, the output is expected to be in textual format, as it typically does not make sense to split binary data on arbitrary time-based intervals.

### ExecuteStreamCommand

> Executes an external command on the contents of a flow file, and creates a new flow file with the results of the command.

Both these definitions mention word *command*; however, one (ExecuteProcess) says it executes an **OS command**, while another (ExecuteStreamCommand) says it executes an **external command**.

What is the difference between these two?

Is my understanding/guess correct, that "OS command" implies something like local OS tools (e. g. `ping`, `curl`, `netstat`, etc.) and "external command" implies something that is not necessarily OS-native, but still runs as a command-line/shell tool on the host OS (e.g. `java -jar somejar.jar`)?

Answer (score 1):

Atleast from my understanding this is what I found out to be the main difference between `ExecuteProcess` and `ExecuteStreamCommand`.

The `ExecuteProcess` processor doesn't support having an incoming connection, so in this case this has to be a process that is independent or the starting point of an job. While the `ExecuteStreamCommand` does allow incoming connections that can read an existing flowfile.

Also, the `ExecuteProcess` would support running command-line/shell tool as you can see in the [documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.20.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteProcess/index.html) it specifies `if just the name of an executable is provided, it must be in the user's environment PATH.`

You can give a quick run to try a sample Java/Python command to test it in NiFi.